# Why does the compiler not recognize some of the functions of a library?

Tags: function, qt, time, localtime, ctime

Why does the compiler not recognize some of the functions of a library?
I have enclosed the `<ctime>` library in Qt but does not recognize its functions.
why? and how can I solve my problem?

Comment: posting code and some error code messages will help us to help you!

Answer (score 0):

ofcourse compiler recognizes libs when they are properly included, functions are properly used (namespaces enclosed etc)

this example shows how to use a `ctime` lib to print the actual date:
Note that the function time is enclosed in the namespace std
therefore `std::time(...)`  is a valid call

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
    std::cout << "x: "<< std::ctime(&result);
    return a.exec();
}
```